# Displaying image file from django model in jade

Tags: node.js, django, pug

I want to render an image file from a django model into a jade template
the model is as follows

```
class Brand
    photo = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to= 'brands')
    photo_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

What is the syntax i use to render it in a jade template?

i do not want to use `STATIC_DIRS`. is there any way to use `MEDIA_ROOT` to display in jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MEDIA_ROOT` is an absolute path and you can set the path in your settings.py file like following:

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/upload')`

And change your `FileField` to `ImageField`

```
photo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to= 'brands')
```

And, you can access the object photo as follows:

```
 <img src="{{ object.photo.url }}">
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to do this without changing MEDIA_ROOT, but by adding a url in urls.py?

Comment: If you don't want to change the MEDIA_ROOT you can simply use following in url
```urlpatterns = patterns('',```
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
````) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, ```document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)```

Comment: and would the jade syntax be the same?

Comment: Now you can access {{MEDIA_ROOT}} in your template and append to {{object.photo.url}}

Comment: Can i use object.photo.url with a FileField as well?

Comment: Yeah. You can use .url property with FileField as well.